# How to instantiate a Scala object from a CSV/Map

Tags: java, scala, class, csv

I am currently working on some Scala script.  I have a dependency library with some Java classes.

A class looks like this :

```
public class Animal {
   protected String name;
   protected String animalBreed;

   public String getName() {
      return this.name;
   }

   public void setName(String value) {
      this.name = value;
   }

   public String getAnimalBreed() {
      return this.animalBreed;
   }

   public void setAnimalBreed(String value) {
      this.animalBreed = value;
   }
}
```

And I have some CSV input files that don't necessarily contain all the fields of the class and might have some other fields that are not defined.

Ex:

```
name,age
Spyke,2
```

I already have some code that transform the CSV into a `Map[String,String]`. But I am looking a way to instantiate my `Animal` class "dynamically". And by dynamically, I mean automatically set the fields available and skip the other ones. In this case it would create a new `Animal` object with a name but no breed and no age.

I don't really know if this is possible in Scala, or what key word would help me do a Google search – any help is appreciated!

Comment: I would suggest using case classes with optional fields (Option) for those fields that might not exist.  In this case you can initialize non-existing fields with None and existing fields with Some(String), for instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import com.github.marklister.collections.io._
import com.github.marklister.collections._
Welcome to Scala version 2.11.6 (OpenJDK Server VM, Java 1.7.0_79).
Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
Type :help for more information.

scala> case class Animal (age: Option[Int], name:  Option[String],breed: Option[String])
defined class Animal

scala> val csv="""15,Cecil,Lion
     | 5,,Pangolin
     | n/a,Kermit,Frog"""
csv: String =
15,Cecil,Lion
5,,Pangolin
n/a,Kermit,Frog

scala> CsvParser(Animal).parse(new java.io.StringReader(csv))
res0: Seq[Animal] = List(Animal(Some(15),Some(Cecil),Some(Lion)), Animal(Some(5),None,Some(Pangolin)), Animal(None,Some(Kermit),Some(Frog)))
```

[product-collections](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections).  Pretty easy huh?

Comment: Quick questions, if one field of the csv is the class that I need to use, will it be possible to parse it ? Something like  CsvParser(myFirstCol).parse(...)

Comment: The parser uses [these converters](https://github.com/marklister/product-collections/blob/master/shared/src/main/scala/collections/io/GeneralConverter.scala) by default.  It's fairly straight forward to define your own converters -- take a look at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

This Scala method can create a new instance of the `Animal` Java class with the fields in `Map[String,String]`.

```
  def createAnimal(fields: Map[String, String]): Animal =
    fields.foldLeft(new Animal) {
      (animal, field) => field._1 match {
        case "name" =>
          animal.setName(field._2)
        case "animalBreed" =>
          animal.setAnimalBreed(field._2)
        case _ =>
      }
      animal
    }
```

Comment: Tanks for your answer, but it means I know the order of the fileds in advance. Do you have a similar solution with any field order? 
for example , if I have a csv with columns : "age, name, animal Breed" your solution wouldn't work. 
thanks

Comment: The order doesn't matter with my solution. The `foldLeft` will iterate over the fields in the `Map` and will apply one case or the other for each field as they appear.